# IAR: type cast in the debugger's watch expression

Tags: c++, debugging, iar

Does anybody know how to cast a variable to a different type in the IAR debugger's watch window?

My current problem is: having a pointer to the object of interface class, I can't access the properties of the implementation class. An example using meta C++ code:

```
struct QuestionIntf {
    virtual int getAnswer() = 0;
};

struct AnswerImpl : public QuestionIntf {
    enum { theAnswer = 42 };
    int getAnswer()
    {
        return theAnswer;
    }
};

// int the code 
QuestionIntf *pQA = new AnswerImpl;
// here I need to inspect the `pQA` as `AnswerImpl`, not `QuestionIntf`
```

So far, all attempts at all known to me syntaxes of type casts have failed. Documentation is very very thin on any kind of in-depth details.

P.S. IAR Embedded Embedded Workbench 6.5

Comment: Have tried using `(AnswerImpl*)pQa` in Quick Watch view?

Comment: I be damned. And two days ago it didn't work at all. :(